# Jmeter: Requirement to Fetch aggregate response time of all the HTTP requests under a transaction controller for each iteration

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

As per our project requirement , we have to write  response time of each transaction to a DB During our Load test.

For web services scripts , we are using prev.getTime() function in Beanshell  and write the response time of that transaction in a DB.

But for UI level scripts , we have to use transaction controller and under the transaction controller many HTTP requests are there. If we use prev.getTime() function it will fetch only the response time of last request .

If some one has solution for the  above requirement,  please share it...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Transaction Controller in `Generate parent sample` mode you can get the total duration of all nested samplers as `prev.getParent().getTime()`

See [SampleResult.getParent()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getParent--) method JavaDoc for details.

---

I would recommend switching either to JSR223 Test Elements and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language, since as when it comes to high loads Beanshell performance might be a big question mark. Groovy is Java-compliant (even more than Beanshell) so most likely you won't have to change a single line of code in order to migrate.

References:

- [BeanShell Scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)